# useNavigate not working, it doesnt redirect me to the specified page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an amazon clone. I finished my payment processing page but the page does not redirect me to the orders page. When I press buy now on the '/payment' page it doesn't redirect me to '/orders'/.Instead it redirects me to '/payments?'    .

I think the issue should be in the handleSubmit function in Payment.js because that's where I use useNavigate() to redirect.

Here is my Payment.js page :

```
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import CurrencyFormat from 'react-currency-format';
import { Link, Navigate, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import CheckoutProduct from './CheckoutProduct';
import './Payment.css';
import { getBasketTotal } from './reducer';
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';
import axios from './axios';

function Payment() {

 const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

 const navigate = useNavigate();

 const stripe = useStripe();
 const elements = useElements();

 const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
 const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
 const [error, setError] = useState(null);
 const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
 const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
        //generate the special stripe secret which allows us to charge a 
        //customer
        const  getClientSecret = async () => {
            const response = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                //Stripe expects the total in a currencies subunits
                url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`
            });
            setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret)
        } 
        
        getClientSecret();

}, [basket])

console.log('THE SECRET IS >>', clientSecret)

const handleSumbit = async (event) => {
    //do some fancy stripe
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true); // this command esentially doesnt allow you to press
    //the buy button 5 times. Your press it once and it disables

   // const payload = await stripe

    const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        }
    }).then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
    //paymentIntent = payment confirmation
        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null)
        setProcessing(false)

        navigate('/orders', { replace: true })
    })
}

const handleChange = event => {
    // Listen for changes in the CardElement
    // and dpslay any errors as the customer types their card details
    setDisabled(event.empty);
    setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");

   
}

 return (
    <div className='payment'>
     <div className='payment__container'>
        <h1>
            Checkout (
                <Link to="/checkout">{basket?.length} items</Link>
                )
        </h1>

        {/* Payment section - delivery adress */}
        <div className='payment__section'>
            <div className='payment__title'>
                <h3>Delivery address</h3>
            </div>
            <div className='payment__address'>
                <p>{user?.email}</p>
                <p>123 React Lane</p>
                <p>Los Angeles, CA</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {/* Payment section - Review Items */}
        <div className='payment__section'>
            <div className='payment__title'>
                <h3>Review items and delivery</h3>
            </div>
            <div className='payment__items'>
                {basket.map(item => (
                    <CheckoutProduct
                        id={item.id}
                        title={item.title}
                        image={item.image}
                        price={item.price}
                        rating={item.rating}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>


        {/* Payment section - Payment method */}
        <div className='payment__section'>
            <div className='payment__title'>
                <h3>Payment Method</h3>
            </div>
                <div className="payment__details">
                        {/* stripe magic will go here*/}

                        <form  onSumbit={handleSumbit}>
                            <CardElement onChange={handleChange} />
                            <div className='payment__priceContainer'>
                                <CurrencyFormat
                                    renderText={(value) => (
                                        <h3>Order Total: {value}</h3>
                                    )}
                                    decimalScale={2}
                                    value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
                                    displayType={"text"}
                                    thousandSeparator={true}
                                    prefix={"€"}
                                />
                                <button disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}>
                                    <span>{processing ? <p>Processing</p> : "Buy Now"}</span>
                                </button>


                            </div>
                            {/* Errors */}
                            {error && <div>{error}</div>}
                        </form>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
)
}

export default Payment
```

, here is the functions/index.js:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe") ("sk_test_51L82r9HuFTJR44r2Eo7mEWknVKQ6EJvIkuQilUW8wi5dEv1zNMwT0kV1aRykaws2lK8vXA28OZ6yhR17eyccFckL00m8NIXFnn");


   // cd to functions not only amazon-clone





// API

// -App config

const app = express();

// -Middlewares

app.use(cors({ origin:true }));
app.use(express.json());


// -Api routes

app.get('/', (request, response) => response.status(200).send('hello world'));

app.post('/payments/create', async (request, response) => {
   const total = request.query.total;

   console.log('Payment Request Recieved BOOM!! for this amnount >>>', total);

   const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
          amount: total,
          currency: "usd",
   });
   //ok -created
   response.status(201).send({
          clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
   });

 });

 // - Listen command

 exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

// Example endpoint
// http://localhost:5001/challenge-132bd/us-central1/api

here is my full github: https://github.com/chip00/Amazon-clone.git

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had written onsubmit wrongly and also you need to be running 'firebase emulators:start' or else you get stuck in proccessing again